# How many objects Java Virtual Machine creates?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, virtual-machine

All classes in Java by default extends Object

```
public class Dog{
    public Dog()
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Dog dog = new Dog();
}
```

If I compile this code JVM will create 2 classes on heap 1- Object 2- Dog. What happens if Dog class implements an Interface and extends an Abstract class?

```
public interface Animal{
}
public abstract class Mammal{
}
```

In this case Dog will implement Animal interface and extend Mammal abstract class:

```
public class Dog extends Mammal implements Animal{
    public Dog();
}
```

When I create a Dog object now like I did before how many objects is the JVM going to create on the heap?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Animal Dog = new Dog();
}
```

And if I create Dog with Animal type, what changes?

Comment: When you create a new `Dog`, there are no separate instances of class `Object` and class `Dog`. There is just one object. No matter how many interfaces class `Dog` implements or what class it extends, it will still be one single object.

Answer (score 1):

You still have just one `Dog` instance, regardless of the interfaces it implements or the classes it extends.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of how many `interface`s your class has implemented, the number of instances created in this case is just one. Whenever you are in doubt, you should think about whether you can instantiate an `interface` or an `abstract class` and you will get, NO as the answer. Thus, there will be only as many instances created as you create using the concrete class which is, `Dog` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your last question : we call this polymorphism

if you have same attribute for both of them it will use which belongs to Dog class